Furnace fan doesn't work in manual mode
I have an older Lennox furnace that was set up with R and W wires to the thermostat only. Very old 2-wire thermostat with no manual fan switch. When the thermostat kicks in to call for heat, the fan starts running automatically after a while and warm air flows. All good.
I have since installed a better thermostat and would like to run the fan manually by means of the G wire. All connected up correctly and everything works as normal in heating mode, including the fan, but when manual fan is selected the fan does not turn on.
First thing was to take my trusty multimeter and noted that there is permanently 24V on the G wire. After disconnecting the thermostat, still 24V on the G wire, so it is the FURNACE that is somehow pulling the G wire permanently to 24V.
QUESTION: Is there a jumper or something on the furnace control board that I need to change in order to allow manual fan control?

Welcome to DIY! No, there isn't anything on the control board that needs to be adjusted. Surely there's a wiring problem to be sorted out. When you measure 24V on the G wire, what's the point of reference? (R or W, I presume) Have you checked the wiring at the furnace end of the cable?

I measure 24V between W and G. Even if I disconnect the wires at the furnace end and measure I still get 24V on the G-terminal at the furnace. So I conclude that the furnace is holding the G wire at 24V but why?

Furnace controls that use the 24 volt 2/4/5-wire control scheme normally have the R terminal connected to one pole of the 24 volt transformer and the C terminal connected to the other pole. The C-side also is frequently connected to the furnace chassis, aka earth ground.
A thermostat signals the furnace control to operate by shorting one of the control lines (W for heat, Y for cooling, G for fan) to the R line. With everything open circuit, one might measure around 24 volts from R to any of W, Y, or G. I say "around" 24 volts because it depends on the circuitry in the furnace control. It used to be that the "circuitry" was just a relay coil, but now that the controls use transistors and other electronics to monitor the inputs, the measured voltage might be something weird, less than the nominal 24 volts.
You can test that the furnace controls are working properly with a jumper wire. Disconnect the thermostat wires, connect the jumper wire from R to G, and close the blower compartment and turn on the furnace power. Heat or cooling can likewise be tested by jumpering R to W or R to Y. Note that the call for cooling does not always automatically turn on the fan; sometimes one must jumper R to both Y and G in order to run the air conditioning compressor and the blower.
Assuming those tests work out OK, have a look at the wiring to the thermostat. It might be that the R and W are swapped somewhere. For heat-only operation everything works even when those are reversed, but when cooling or fan come into the picture, then it does matter.

@Greg Hill gave me the clue I needed when he said if the R and W wires are swapped around, heating will work normally but no fan. Makes perfect sense when you think about it.
Anyway, I double-checked on the furnace end and found that back in 1987 when it was installed the tech had indeed switched the R and W wires at the furnace end. DOH!!!

Where in the furnace were the R and W wires switched?

Where they attached to the furnace. Both wires were covered in white paint from years ago so I needed to scrape off the paint to verify which wire I was working with. Once I did that it all fell into place.

My 25 year old Lennox had the red wire from the blower connected to the Park M1 terminal on the board. I moved the red wire to the ACB terminal and the primary fan switch began to work properly.
